# Make xf:output a clickable link

Tags: html, xquery, xforms, exist-db

I have an xquery where an instance is defined:

```
    <xf:instance id="table" xmlns="">
        <results>
            <result>
                <interfaceName></interfaceName>
                <reportDate></reportDate>
                <testResult></testResult>
                <fileLink></fileLink>
                <fileName></fileName>
            </result>
        </results>
    </xf:instance>
```

Later I 'replace' this instance by submission and retrieving information from another xquery:

```
<xf:submission id="showTable"
                        method="post" 
                        replace="instance"
                        ref="instance('table')"
                        instance="table">
                <xf:resource value="concat('/exist/rest/db/xquery/returnTable.xq?interface=',instance('defaultInstance')//InterfaceName,'&amp;','date=',instance('defaultInstance')//CalendarDate)"/>        
            </xf:submission>
```

Returned 'table' instance looks like:

```
<results>
<result>
<interfaceName>test1</interfaceName>
<reportDate>2016-06-01</reportDate>
<testResult>failure</testResult>
<fileLink>http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/junitReports/Report2.xml</fileLink>
<fileName>/db/junitReports/Report2.xml</fileName>
</result>
<result>
<interfaceName>test2</interfaceName>
<reportDate>2016-06-01</reportDate>
<testResult>success</testResult>
<fileLink>http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/junitReports/Report1.xml</fileLink>
<fileName>/db/junitReports/Report1.xml</fileName>
</result>
</results>
```

Then I am trying to build a table by referencing values in this returned instance:

```
<tbody xf:repeat-nodeset="instance('table')//result">
                   <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xf:output ref="interfaceName"></xf:output>   
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xf:output ref="reportDate"></xf:output> 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xf:output ref="testResult"></xf:output>  
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <li>
                                <!-- <a href="{concat(request:get-scheme(), "://", request:get-server-name(),":", '8080', '/exist/rest', fileLink )}">Link</a> -->
                                <xf:output ref="fileLink"></xf:output>
                            </li>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

The issue is that the last column should become a clickable link and I did not find a way to do it.

I tried to make a fileLink element in 'table' instance an URL by specifying its type:

```
<xf:bind nodeset="instance('table')//result/fileLink" type="anyURI"></xf:bind>
```

But this makes only value in the first row of the table a link. In all next records this column remains a plane text.

I would rather use a simple href (you can see it commented out there), but I do not know how to obtain a value from fileLink element?

This does not work because fileName is not concatenated to the string (I think it is not found):

```
<a href="{concat(request:get-scheme(), "://", request:get-server-name(),":", '8080', '/exist/rest', fileName)}">Link</a>
```

and this does not work (which is obvious, but I still tried)

```
<a href="fileLink">Link</a>
```

In both possible solution I do not know: How can I refer to fileLink element in pure HTML to get it working with href if I decide to use it (preferable for me solution)? How can I make not only the first occurrence of the field a clickable link, but all the next as well if I use xf:output and xf:bind instead of href?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This solved the issue:

```
                <td>
                    <xf:trigger appearance="minimal">
                        <xf:label>File link</xf:label>
                        <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
                            <xf:load show="new">
                                <xf:resource value="fileLink"/>
                            </xf:load>
                        </xf:action>
                    </xf:trigger>
                </td>
```